# Retrieving/Posting Images From MongoDB (mongoose)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I've been trying to work with images in mongodb for the past while now. Every where I keep looking just says use GridFS due to the 16mb size restraint per document. However, each document Id like to store is <16mb. I currently stored it like this

```
var testChamp = new Champion ({
    name: "Aatrox",
    img: fs.readFileSync("D:/CounterMe/Aatrox_0.jpg"),
    contentType: "jpg"
});
testChamp.save(function() {
    console.log("Saved");
})
```

In my schema:

```
name: String,
img: Buffer,
contentType: String `
```

Finding this information in the mongoshell brings a HUGE amount of lines in cmd, so Im not sure if im even storing it correctly. If I am, I have no clue how to insert it into my html. I know how to retrieve the name, pass it in as an object:

```
app.get("/", function(req, response) {
    Champion.find(function(err, champs) {            
        response.render("index", {
        champ: champs[0]
        });            
    });
});
```

However, once I retrieve champs[0].img, im not sure what to do with it. How am I supposed to pass the img into my HTML? Any help would be appreciated, I am very stumped currently.

Comment: This might be helpful https://gist.github.com/aheckmann/2408370

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked this question when I was first getting into web development. Coming back to it 5 years later, my approach was definitely wrong. I was trying to store my images themselves in mongodb, when I should have been storing them in a storage service like S3, then just storing the urls to said images in mongodb. Hopefully this helps someone who comes across this!

Comment: You are right, external storage like S3 is the correct approach.  Referencing an image in a storage location is not only easier to understand and program it eliminates the CPU intensive job of turning a Buffer into an image.

Answer (score 2):

You really shouldn't be trying to render in HTML. I've seen approaches and they are all generally bad, and for one good reason.

The browser implements a cache, and as such any "images" it has retrieved before will be held in that cache. But if you are somehow attempting to "embed" that image data ( via Base64 encoding for example ) you are basically throwing away that caching capability and causing that data to be sent with every request.

If you must store images in MongoDB in this way then you should have a seperate endpoint in your API which would return what would be basically just an image. So make all requests "look like" they are just fetching an image from the web server.

First change your data a little to reflect what would be a "filename":

```
var testChamp = new Champion ({
    name: "aatrox.jpg",
    img: fs.readFileSync("D:/CounterMe/Aatrox_0.jpg"),
    contentType: "image/jpg"
});
```

Then you would have controller code like this:

```
app.get("/images/:image", function(req,res) {
    Champion.findOne({ "name": req.param.image },function(err,champ) {
       res.set("Content-Type", champ.contentType);
       res.send( champ.img );
    });
});
```

In your templates you then just refer to the URL of the image as you ordinarily would. You can add to that and possibly even store things like content length and set that in the response header as well. There are modules that you can use to detect mime-type and size from images uploaded through another API point prior to storing them as well. Have a look around for these.

This makes sense and is much more efficient than otherwise sending all of the image data within the HTML.

Comment: Are one of these modules GridFS?

Comment: @user3851102 GridFS is an entirely different thing. It's purpose is storing documents larger than the 16MB BSON limit. It is a driver spec and not a module or software in itself in any form. There is a lot of misinformation out there that says you use GridFS for image storage. It is all false. Under 16MB there is nothing wrong with just storing and retrieving the image data in MongoDB just as you are. Just don't try to embed in HTML responses as that is bad.

Comment: Sorry, Im kind of confused about what you mean embeding HTML responses. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: @ShameelAbdullah You question asks how do render the image in the template. My response says don't try an render in the template just return the image data from a standard URL. Your template content and the image should be served in separate requests.

Comment: Ok, that cleared it up alot. I just understood the message. Was just a little confused